# Scalatest and Anorm in playframework

Tags: playframework, scalatest, anorm

I'm working on a playframework project, and we test using scalatest. We also want to do some database tests. In conf/application.conf we set up a database connection, but this seems to be ignored when we launch our tests. How can we configure this?

Comment: play or play 2.0? matters a lot, the APIs diverged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests needs to be run within the FakeApplication context. You could wrap every test like this (using FunSpec):

```
describe("MyEntity") {
  it("should do something") {
    running(FakeApplication()) {
      MyEntity.findById(1L).value.name should be("some name")
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to repeat this for every test you can use several methods, see scalatest docs for info about how to share fixures: [sharing fixtures](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures)

Comment: how can i make this use a test database, defined in the .conf, instead of the default database?

Comment: That is described here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTest

Basically you pass extra config using an "additionalConfiguration" map:

`FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())`

Pass your own options to override the database-related settings (driver, connection url etc) if the inMemoryDatabase is not what you want.

Comment: Add a new test.conf within conf/, which includes your Application.conf and then overrides the database settings. You can then load this configuration file when running tests by adding `javaOptions in Test ++= Seq( "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf")` to your build.sbt